# Jenkins MKS Integrity Plugin only populating folder structure, not files

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, redhat, mks, mks-integrity

I've recently been trying to set up a Jenkins server that uses the Jenkins MKS plugin for version control. I had a Windows Jenkins server that was running this same configuration just fine, and now that we're moving it to a linux server (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.1 Tikanga), it doesn't seem to be able to download the files. The folder structure is built perfectly fine, which tells me connecting to the server isn't the problem, but the files aren't populated in the folders.

**Jenkins System Log:**

`Sep 02, 2016 11:15:46 AM WARNING org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase readResponseBody
Unsupported transfer encoding: 
Sep 02, 2016 11:15:46 AM INFO org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase readResponseBody Response 
content is not chunk-encoded
Sep 02, 2016 11:15:46 AM INFO hudson.model.Run execute
Test #67 main build action completed: FAILURE`

Any suggestions on what I can do to check if my data/files are chunk encoded, or why this would be unique to a linux server? I realize we’re 3+ years behind on our configuration, but IT here has tight restrictions on what software can be installed and updated. Any troubleshotting suggestions or help is much appreciated!

**Config Details:**

> Jenkins Version 1.596.3
>
> MKS Plugin Version 1.16 MKS Server: MKS Integrity Client 2009, Build
>   4.10.0.9665, SP 007-01
>
> Jenkins Slave info: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.1
>   (Tikanga)
>
> Java version 1.7.0 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) Server_VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)

**Similar issues / Research:**

This issue report perfectly describes my problem, but the comment section suggests that the Java 7u40 update causes the issue, whereas I'm on an earlier version of Java.
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21638

This issue describes the log error I'm seeing, but comment section suggests it was solved by Jenkins version 1.577. We're using a newer version of Jenkins. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16985

Answer (score 0):

You're using Integrity 10.9:  As per the **Version 2.0 (Jan 27, 2016)** entry on the [Plug-in's page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PTC+Integrity+Plugin):

- IMPORTANT – PTC Integrity Plugin 2.0 is not backward compatible.
  Please create new Jobs.
- Productized version of PTC Integrity Plugin
  compatible with PTC Integrity 10.9. Versions older than Integrity
  10.9 are no longer supported.

I think what Cletus is trying to explain in that post is that both the version of Java used to build the plug-in and the version of Java running Integrity should be the same, and in the case linked for [JENKINS-21638](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21638), changes in the 'File' object after Java 7u40 are preventing the plug-in from fetching files from the server.

If you were on a version of Java earlier than 7u40 (e.g. 7u25) it should work.  Integrity 2009 SP6 (and hence the mksapi.jar file) were compiled with Java 6, so it's likely you're running into a similar issue there.  Having said that, I'm working on an educated guess here, so you'd actually need to test that to see if it works.